# Complete tree of height n. A formula in FO.

Tags: first-order-logic, trees

Let $T$ be a family of finite binary trees under the signature contains two realational symbols:
$$ l(y,x) \iff  \text{ y is left son of x }$$
$$ r(y,x) \iff  \text{ y is right son of x }$$
Prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists a such FO two-varviables-sentence $\phi_n$ that for every finite tree $t$ it is true:
$$ t \models \phi_n \iff t \text { is complete and its height equals to n}$$.

My solution:
Induction by height of tree:

Let $\phi_1 = \exists x [ (\exists y l(y,x) \wedge (\neg \exists x  l(x,y) \vee r(x,y))) \wedge (\exists y r(y,x) \wedge (\neg \exists x  l(x,y) \vee r(x,y))) ]$. It means that $x$ is a root of complete tree where its height = 1.

Induction step:
Let $\phi_n(x) $ will be a such two-variable-sentence that: $$ t \models \phi_n(x) \iff \text{ t is a complete tree. Its height = n}$$

Now, we define the $$\phi_{n+1}(x) = (\exists y l(y,x) \wedge \phi_n[y/x]) )  \wedge (\exists y r(y,x) \wedge \phi_n[y/x])$$

Now, $phi_{n+1}(x) $ has no free variables.

Now, we can note that if $t \models \phi_{n+1}(x)$ then $t$ is a complete tree, its height = $n+1$. $\phi_{n+1}(x)$ is still 2-variables because the induction step doesnt introduce new variables.

Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that $\varphi_1$ isn't a sentence; it has a free variable $x$. So you need to tweak it.

Even then, you're not quite done: $\varphi_1$ (when fixed) will say that $t$ *extends* a complete tree of height $1$. How do you know, for instance, that $t$ isn't a complete tree of height $17$? Intuitively, your formulas need to do two things: say that $t$ is *at least* a complete tree of height $n$, and also say that $t$ isn't *more* than that. (Your inductive step is fine, *after you fix the base case*.)

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: @Logic Still a problem - you've written "Every $y$ is a left successor and right successor of $x$." You were closer before. HINT: do you know how to right "there are exactly three elements" in first-order logic?

Comment: I've edited again. @NoahSchweber, I know but I don't know how to express it having only 2 variables.